# android listview onclick button

Tags: android

Edited, thnx 4 de answer but wht I meant is this-have populated listview with image,Id,and name of candidates from mysql database. Made a custom adapter with android  vote button, which auto generate on every candidate in the listview. So what I want is when a voter clicks on the vote button either Id, or name is sent 2 database and then increase number of votes by +1 in the vote field of the database. Android voting app using php(android and php)Any1 pliz help.

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple You can do this by getting your current count from database then increment the same in your Android code and then update the database with new value that you just incremented.